# BackgroundContainer.dll for HP ProBook

Tags: windows

I have an HP ProBook. When I start my PC, on the desktop a window appears that says:

```
There was a problem starting C:\User\HP Probook\AppData\Local\Conduit\BackgroundContainer\BackgroundContainer.dll  
The specified module could not be Found.
```

Comment: You probably installed some software by Conduit Ltd and that's why you get this message. Try to remove it manually from your browser and from any file you find in your PC.
Here, those might be handy http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/protect/forum/protect_scanner-protect_scanning/run-dll-error-messagebackground-containerdll/49612202-667e-4a71-8e9a-d02161d8bc19
http://www.xp-vista.com/spyware-removal/rundll-error-messagebackground-container-dll-removal-guide

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get rid of malicious spyware, malware, viruses or rootkits from my PC?](http://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-do-i-get-rid-of-malicious-spyware-malware-viruses-or-rootkits-from-my-pc)

Comment: You should follow the instructions listed here: http://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-do-i-get-rid-of-malicious-spyware-malware-viruses-or-rootkits-from-my-pc

Your computer is likely suffering under a viral infection.

Answer (score 1):

That seems to be a piece of Conduit, you should uninstall that!

Conduit Search is a form of spyware / malware. It is best to uninstall it, then run Malwarebytes anti malware to fully ensure it's removal. Download and Install MalwareBytes Anti-Malware, run a full Scan. Malware-Bytes trial version will be sufficient enough, don't worry about buying a license.